# Store formatted MS Word text to MySQL database and retrieve it into new document

Tags: ms-word, formatting

I'm able to use VBA, or VBScript, or `python-docx`, or `pandas` (when saving a Word file in a HTML format) to get plain text from tables in a Word document. This text further can be stored to MySQL database. But I need to get also the text's formatting, like bold/italic text, subscript/superscript etc. Is there a way to save text as plain text with tags, like in LaTeX or HTML, and also retrieve it to create a new Word document?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157999/how-to-extract-rtf-html-text-from-a-word-document

Comment: Depends partly on how much fidelity you need, whether you would prefer to avoid "save to disk" operations, whether it is OK to modify the clipboard, and how much text you want to store for each chunk of text. E.g. If you get the XML of a Word Range object, it's in-memory, but you get a complete Word Flat OPC document even if your text is only 1  character long. It also stores style info., so there's the question of what happens if you insert that into another document with clashing styles.

Comment: @jonsson I only need to get information from some table cells, formatting can be restricted to subscript, superscript and line breaks. But yes, I also need to create new documents and insert text with formatting from database.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you could approach this, and they all have their complications and limitations, unless you are willing to identify and fix every possible point of failure. I've had to rush so this is very unpolished.

Here, I have tried to provide an example that takes the material in a single table cell, and generates a valid Office Open "XML snippet" that will preserve "ordinary", subscripted, and superscripted characters, paragraph marks and hard returns using the Office Open XML (OOXML) elements `<w:p>`, `<w:r>`, `<w:t>`, `<w:rPr>`, `<w:br>`, and `<w:vertAlign>`. I probably should have considered <w:tab> but ran out of time for now. So as you can tell, it's not much tested either. Two constrints are that the code won't work if you have any nested tables in your cells, can't currently detect inline graphics (I think they will appear as / characters if you have any), and there may well be other things to avoid. It also assumes that all characters are Unicode and will not deal correctly with, say, a Wingdings character.

The idea is that you would just store the XML snippet in your database, so you don't have to store an entire OOML document for every chunk of cell text. When you want to re-insert the cell content in another document, you surround XML snippet with a standard (fairly) minimal OOXML "head and tail" to create a valid OOXML document.

Put everything in a single VBA module, starting with this, which sets up a number of string constants containing bits of XML. I use the suffix "a" for a "start tag" or "start chunk" and the suffix "z" for an "end tag" or "end chunk"

```
Option Explicit

Const xa As String = _
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>" & vbCr & _
"<?mso-application progid='Word.Document'?>" & vbCr & _
"<pkg:package xmlns:pkg='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage'>" & vbCr & _
"  <pkg:part pkg:name='/_rels/.rels' pkg:contentType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml'>" & vbCr & _
"    <pkg:xmlData>" & vbCr & _
"      <Relationships xmlns='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships'>" & vbCr & _
"        <Relationship Id = 'rId1' Type='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument'" & vbCr & _
"           Target='word/document.xml'/>" & vbCr & _
"        </Relationships>" & vbCr & _
"      </pkg:xmlData>" & vbCr & _
"    </pkg:part>" & vbCr & _
"  <pkg:part pkg:name='/word/document.xml' pkg:contentType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml'>" & vbCr & _
"    <pkg:xmlData>" & vbCr & _
"      <w:document xmlns:w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'>" & vbCr & _
"        <w:body>" & vbCr

Const xz As String = _
"        </w:body>" & vbCr & _
"      </w:document>" & vbCr & _
"    </pkg:xmlData>" & vbCr & _
"  </pkg:part>" & vbCr & _
"</pkg:package>" & vbCr

Const xbr As String = "<w:br/>"
Const xpa As String = "<w:p>"
Const xpz As String = "</w:p>"
Const xra As String = "<w:r>"
Const xrz As String = "</w:r>"
Const xta As String = "<w:t>"
Const xtz As String = "</w:t>"

Const xsub As String = "<w:rPr><w:vertAlign w:val='subscript'/></w:rPr>"
Const xsup As String = "<w:rPr><w:vertAlign w:val='superscript'/></w:rPr>"
```

A simple Sub shows how you would insert a piece of OOXML (which might look like <w:p><w:r><w:t>Hello World!</w:t></w:r></w:p> into the current Selection in a Word document. You can modify this to insert into a specified range or cell. There may be locations where Word will raise an error if you try to insert XML, But be aware during testing that one of the common errors Word rasies usually means that the XML is not valid (even though the message does not say so).

```
Sub insertOOXMLSnippet(s As String)
Debug.Print xa & s & xz
Selection.InsertXML xa & s & xz
End Sub
```

The following routine takes a Word Range and converts it into a chunk of OOXML as discussed above. In fact it currently relies on the Range being the content of a Table Cell.

```
Function OOXMLSnippet(r As Word.Range) As String
Dim c As Word.Range
Dim i As Long
Dim s As String
Dim startedRun As Boolean
Dim startedSubscript As Boolean
Dim startedSuperscript As Boolean
Dim startedText As Boolean

s = xpa
With r
  With .TextRetrievalMode
    .IncludeFieldCodes = False
    ' you also need to consider whether or not you need
    '.IncludeHiddenText = True
  End With
  
  startedRun = False
  startedSubscript = False
  startedSuperscript = False
  startedText = False

  For Each c In r.Characters
    Select Case c.Text
    Case ChrW(13) & ChrW(7) ' end of enclosing table cell
      ' we are not allowing nested tables in this example,
      ' so we know this terminates the cell
        Debug.Print AscW(Left(c.Text, 1)), AscW(Right(c.Text, 1))
        If startedText Then
          s = s & xtz
        End If
        If startedRun Then
          s = s & xrz
        End If


    Case "", ChrW(0) To ChrW(8), ChrW(10), ChrW(12), ChrW(14) To ChrW(31) ' Don't know what this means yet
      If c.Text <> "" Then ' may as well if these occur...
        'Debug.Print AscW(c.Text)
      End If
      
    Case ChrW(13)
      If startedText Then
        s = s & xtz
        startedText = False
      End If
      If startedRun Then
        s = s & xrz
        startedRun = False
      End If
      s = s & xpz & xpa
      startedSubscript = False
      startedSuperscript = False
    
    Case ChrW(11)
      If startedText Then
        s = s & xtz
        startedText = False
      End If
      If startedRun Then
        s = s & xrz
        startedRun = False
      End If
      s = s & xra & xbr & xrz
      startedSubscript = False
      startedSuperscript = False
      
    Case Else
      If c.Font.Subscript Then
        If startedSubscript Then
          s = s & XMLEscape(c.Text)
        Else
          If startedText Then
            s = s & xtz
          End If
          If startedRun Then
            s = s & xrz
          End If
          s = s & xra & xsub & xta & XMLEscape(c.Text)
          startedRun = True
          startedSubscript = True
          startedSuperscript = False
          startedText = True
        End If
      ElseIf c.Font.Superscript Then
        If startedSuperscript Then
          s = s & XMLEscape(c.Text)
        Else
          If startedText Then
            s = s & xtz
          End If
          If startedRun Then
            s = s & xrz
          End If
          s = s & xra & xsup & xta & XMLEscape(c.Text)
          startedRun = True
          startedSubscript = False
          startedSuperscript = True
          startedText = True
        End If
      Else ' neither super nor sub
        If startedSubscript Or startedSuperscript Then
          s = s & xtz & xrz & xra & xta & XMLEscape(c.Text)
          startedSubscript = False
          startedSuperscript = False
          startedRun = True
          startedText = True
        Else
          If Not startedRun Then
            s = s & xra
            startedRun = True
          End If
          If Not startedText Then
            s = s & xta
            startedText = True
          End If
          s = s & XMLEscape(c.Text)
        End If
     End If
     End Select
  Next
End With
OOXMLSnippet = s & xpz
End Function
```

The following is a helper routine to escape the 5 characters you need to escape. 16-bit Unicode characters seem to be handled OK (despite the fact that the document encoding is specified as UTF-8, but that needs to be explored).

```
Function XMLEscape(s As String) As String
' Assumes s is 1 character long. Probably won't work correctly with
' 32-byte private zone characters and planes above 1
' We only need to transform our text characters in ths code
' as the element tags and attributes are all OK anyway.
Select Case s
Case """"
  XMLEscape = "&quot;"
Case "'"
  XMLEscape = "&apos;"
Case "<"
  XMLEscape = "&lt;"
Case ">"
  XMLEscape = "&gt;"
Case "&"
  XMLEscape = "&amp;"
Case Else
  XMLEscape = s
End Select
End Function
```

The following simple example picks up the text from cell 1 of table 1 of the ActiveDocument, converts it into an XML snippet, then inserts it in the current selection.

```
Sub testOOXMLSnippet()
  Call insertOOXMLSnippet(OOXMLSnippet(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells(1).Range))
End Sub
```

The reason I have a preference for using OOXML rather than HTML as an intermediate format is that, although in some respects it's simpler to get what you need from filtered HTML, you have either to go through the clipboard (non-trivial in Word VBA) or save each chunk to an external file, and when re-inserting an "HTML snippet", AFAIK you also have to save to a file first, then insert the file. It may be possible to avoid that using OOXML with an AltChunk to insert the HTML but I *think* the AltChunk has to reference an external file. Perhaps someone here knows better. OOXML is in theory capable of representing any text/formatting in a Word document. Neither HTML nor RTF does that any more. Personally I think RTF is also much more opaque thatn OOXML.

The problem with the XML that Word gereates is that it has a lot of stuff in that you just don't need, or which would force you to store the entire document for each snippet, because otherwise there will probably be broken references. Then there's the question of what happens when you re-insert all that formatting that came from one document into another document with completely different formatting.

If you find it easy to work with XML programmatically, you may find it easier to remove all the stuff you don't need by removing unwanted elements and attributes using, say, MSXML6 or another method. But even then, the way Word constructs its XML is sometimes very unhelpful. For example, in my test data I had a paragraph with plain text, subscripted text, and superscripted text. In the OOXML, the paragraph had a Parapgrah Properties element <w:pPr> containing a RUn properties element that basically specified that the default format for all the runs in the paragraph was "Subscript". Confusing. So that's why it seems to me to be simpler to generate the XML you need than the modify the XML that Word generates.